# Need a query to retrieve records from many to many table

Tags: sql, database

Table structure:

**role_assignment**

```
 id | contextid | userid    
----+-----------+--------
  1 |        17 |      3    
  2 |        23 |      3
```

**context**

```
 id | instanceid
----+------------
 17 |          2
 23 |          3
```

**course**

```
 id | name
----+----------
  2 | course 1
  3 | course 2
```

I need to retrieve all course names for e.g. `userid = 3` (or any other)

#### Edit

I think this works:

```
SELECT course.shortname FROM role_assignments, context, course
WHERE userid = 3
  AND role_assignments.contextid = context.id
  AND context.instanceid = course.id;
```

But can anyone improve this using joins?

Comment: What have you tried?  You'll get down-voted pretty quickly if you don't even show that you tried something.

Comment: edited, please enhance using joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming instanceid of context matches to the "id" column of course, the following query will return what you want:

```
select name from course where id in (select c.instanceid from context c, role_assignment b where c.id=b.contextid and b.userid=3);

+----------+
| name     |
+----------+
| course 1 |
| course 2 |
+----------+
```

Using a join the query will be:

```
select distinct name from role_assignment join context on role_assignment.contextid = context.id  join course on context.instanceid = course.id where userid=3;
```

Note you need to use distinct to return unique results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT course.shortname 
FROM role_assignments INNER JOIN context
ON role_assignments.contextid = context.id
INNER JOIN course
ON context.instanceid = course.id
WHERE userid = 3
```